# Value from CSS root variable is not affecting on HTML

Tags: html, css, typescript, sass

I am trying to set text color on `home.html`. Property of color is set in `:root variable` but it is not getting effected on HTML page.

Here is my code:

`home.scss`

```
:root {
--prim-headclr : #004c3f;
}

/* heading */
.phead_clr{
    color:var(--prim-headclr);
}
```

`home.html`

```
    <div class="col-md-12 phead_clr">
        <h1>Build an online business—no matter what business you’re in</h1>
    </div>
```

Why is the given color in root variable not affecting on the HTML side?

Comment: add `phead_clr` class to h1.

Answer (score 1):

Add this 'phead_clr' class to h1.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1 class="phead_clr"> build an online business—no matter what business you’re in</h1>
</div>
```

*** if the css being overwritten by other variables or default variables, then you can also add important.

```
:root {
  --prim-headclr : #004c3f !important;
}
```